# Boto3 IAM waiter isn't waiting

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm using boto3 to create an IAM user, wait until the IAM user is created, then update the login profile of that user. My python code to create the user works fine, and the user is created successfully. IAM is eventually consistent, so I know that I need to wait for the user to be created before I can do anything else with it, and I am using a waiter for that purpose. But when I try to update the login profile, it errors out saying that the user doesn't exist yet.

So basically the waiter isn't waiting like it should.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import boto3

password = 'not_the_real_password'

client = boto3.client('iam')

# Create the user
response = client.create_user(
    UserName='someuser'
)

# Creating the user works fine. But IAM is eventually consistent, so we have
# to wait for the user to be created before we can do anything with it.
waiter = client.get_waiter('user_exists')
waiter.wait(UserName='someuser')

# If the waiter worked correctly, then it should have waited for the user
# to be created before updating the login profile.
response = client.update_login_profile(
    UserName='someuser',
    Password=password,
    PasswordResetRequired=True
)
```

Expected result: the waiter should wait long enough that the IAM user exists, and then updating the login profile would work as expected.

Actual result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_user.py", line 20, in <module>
    PasswordResetRequired=True
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException: An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the UpdateLoginProfile operation: Login Profile for User someuser cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> Login Profile for User someuser cannot be found.

The **Login Profile** is separate to the **User**. It needs to be specifically created.

Change `update_login_profile()` into `create_login_profile()`.